# Create Varilable as Boolean in RDLC report to represent if dollar sign should be printed or not

Tags: variables, reporting-services, report, reporting, ssrs-2012

I am designing an invoice using rdlc file in visual studio (ssrs). Per invoice may have 1-10 transaction. We'd like to present the dollar sign of the amount on the first result only. The rest wouldn't have the dollar sign in front. How to achieve this in rdlc ? Im thinking of using a variable, that if it first, then set it to true. If true then print the sign. Though im not sure how to use variables in rdlc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnLRw.png)

Comment: you might be able to use an expression in the FORMAT property of the text box something like `=IIF(Fields!Description.Value = FIRST(Fields!Description.Value), "c2", "f2")`

Comment: How do I set the field description ?

Comment: I used `Description` as that is what is shown in your example screen shot. Replace `Description` with whatever field is actually used in the report. All this tries to do is say "is the value in column X the same as the first value in column X, if so use currency format, if not use a standard number format"

Comment: ahhhhh now i get it!!! will try this. THANK YOU !!

Comment: it didn't work. all the entries got the currency rather than number

Comment: Can you show your actual report design including any row groups or column groups. My guess is that you need to specify a scope on the `FIRST` function something like `= FIRST(Fields!Description.Value, "myRowGroupName")` where `myRowGroupName` is either the name of the RowGroup of the name of the dataset.